# Protocol and server of chat.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, chat, irc

What's the protocol and server address for "chat.stackoverflow.com" ? I want to connect to it using a messaging client like Pidgin (or XChat or Empathy) if possible. Is the protocol IRC? And What's the server's address (for example, irc.freenode.net)?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82840/so-chat-plugin-for-pidgin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Overflow chat uses an inhouse system, not IRC. There is an [IRC bridge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat/59780#59780) and a[n XMPP bridge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat), but both are experimental & community based.

Comment: Thanks, I try it to make it work, but I wish there was a Pidgin plugin for this SO protocol.