# SO (chat) Plugin for Pidgin

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Belongs these:

[IRC access for the chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat/59780#59780)

[Offer an XMPP method for chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat)

[Protocol and server of chat.stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82412/protocol-and-server-for-chat-stackoverflow-com)

I think a plugin for Pidgin (popular free/open source messaging client) that adds support for SO protocol (used in StackOverflow chat) is really needed.
Sorry, I myself have no experince with network programming and writing plugin for pidgin. But maybe somebody was intrested
to do that. If nobody found, maybe I try myself to do that.

Comment: Old one, but still interesting.