# Can I connect to chat rooms with an external client?

Tags: feature-request, chat, client

I would really like to connect to the javascript chat room with the ubuntu chat client which supports irc, jabber, aim, msn, and every other protocol under the sun.

How are the stackoverflow chat rooms implemented? Is it possible to connect to them with an external client?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82412/protocol-and-server-for-chat-stackoverflow-com, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat/59780#59780 if you're wiling to build it yourself... also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82840/so-chat-plugin-for-pidgin

Comment: Sounds like it is possible but you have to run a bridge yourself (and also maybe the bridge is currently broken?). Thanks for the answer.