# How can I connect to a chat room with pidgin?

Tags: support, chat

I would like to know how to add my Stack Overflow chat account to the Pidgin Instant Messenger client.

Could you share your ideas?

Comment: Consider using the web client. I usually hate web-based chats but the SO chat is extremely awesome.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, not without external software that creates a bridge.

See [this project to create a IRC bridge](https://github.com/ghewgill/soirc) as a starting point if you want to build one yourself. Or try and help out with the [XMPP bridge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat) for a different angle to the problem.