# Answer notification via XMPP

Tags: feature-request, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add XMPP (Jabber/GTalk) notifications in addition to the RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/please-add-xmpp-jabber-gtalk-notifications-in-addition-to-the-rss-feeds)

It would be great to specify JID in account settings (globally for all stackexchange sites) for getting notification on new answers. Probably, optimal variant would be to add another checkbox under "Notify daily of any new answers".